# With Keycloak Java connector, how to get custom group attributes without using getGroupByPath?

Tags: java, keycloak

We used to access the groups attributes thanks to getGroupByPath function like this:

```
GroupRepresentation group = realm.getGroupByPath(Constants.SLASH + groupName);
List<String> displayNames = group.getAttributes().get(Constants.ATTRIBUT_NAME_DISPLAY_NAME);
String displayName = displayNames.get(0);
```

Unfortunately `getGroupByPath` implementation doesn't work with a high number of groups (we have more than 20K groups included 6K root groups). So we access the GroupRepresentation object with `realm.groups().groups(groupName, 0, 1)`. This works fine but the given object **doesn't contain the group's attributes** :( .

Is there a way to access the groups' attributes without using **getGroupByPath** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank to my collegue Leo HP, we found a workaround, if not a solution:

```
List<GroupRepresentation> groupList = realm.groups().groups(groupName, 0, 1);
GroupResource groupResource = realm.groups.group(groupList.get(0).getId());
GroupRepresentation group = groupResource.toRepresentation();

List<String> displayNames = group.getAttributes().get(Constants.ATTRIBUT_NAME_DISPLAY_NAME);
String displayName = displayNames.get(0);
```

Bravo!

Answer (score 0):

```
List<GroupRepresentation> groupList = realm.groups().groups(groupName, 0, 1,false);
```

> briefRepresentation parameter must be false for reaching attributes directly.